# What type of autowiring happens when i use @Autowired for class reference, and if do not use "autowire" attribute for bean definition in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, autowired

In Spring,
I have a controller "BaseController" and have a reference for service class as

```
@Controller
class BaseController{
     @Autowired
     private BaseService baseService;
     //......
}
```

and bean definition in xml as

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean name="baseService" class="com.test.service.BaseService" />
```

Here i'm not using the "autowire" attribute and so not defining the autowire type as either "byType" or "byName".

So now what type of autowiring happens.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, sorry i had modified the question. Could you plz share your ideas for this question.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it in a new post. Rollback this one. As it stands, however, it's very unclear what you're asking. So I would work on clarifying it before asking it in a new post.

Comment: done, could you please share your ideas on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001686/how-autowired-works-if-autowired-is-set-on-propertyclass-which-is-only-decl